# The easy way to code-golf ascii art!

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

## Task:

> There are a lot of answers on this site that are arranged into ascii art, like [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26396/16472). Usually the arrangement is done manually, but wouldn't a program help with that? :)

Your program will take 3 inputs:

- The code, as one single line
- The number of lines in the pattern (can be omitted if not necessary)
- The pattern itself, as `*`s or another char

## Rules:

- You have to write a program (not a function) that reads from stdin
- The text is placed left-to-right per line
- If there is not enough text to fill the pattern, put `.`s in the remaining spaces
- If there is too much text to fill the pattern, print it out after the output
- [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code, in bytes wins

## Sample Runs:

**Input (Exact Fit test)**:

```
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
4
***** * ***
*   * * *
*   * * *
***** * ***
```

**Output**:

```
qwert y uio
p   a s d
f   g h j
klzxc v bnm
```

**Input (Extra characters test)**:

```
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm12345
4
***** * ***
*   * * *
*   * * *
***** * ***
```

**Output**:

```
qwert y uio
p   a s d
f   g h j
klzxc v bnm
12345
```

**Input (Insufficient Characters test)**:

```
qwertyuiopasdfg
4
***** * ***
*   * * *
*   * * *
***** * ***
```

**Output**:

```
qwert y uio
p   a s d
f   g . .
..... . ...
```

Comment: What assumptions should be made about where it's permissible to insert spaces and newlines without changing the semantics of the program?

Comment: @PeterTaylor in the output?

Comment: @PeterTaylor it seems there is no leeway for placing/separating the code, so I suppose semantics are ignored?

Comment: @TheDoctor, where else?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I would agree with m.buettner, the program will not check if a function name is broken by a line (or something like that)

Comment: Thinking about it, there *would* be leeway if you are allowed to insert comments if you can't fit another valid token into the line. For languages where comments need at least two consecutive characters that wouldn't guarantee solubility (without destroying semantics), but it would help.

Comment: "so the shortest code, in bytes wins". This sentence isn't well-formed. Either specify the encoding in which you want to count the bytes, or use the term "character"/codepoint.

Comment: Do the "can be omitted" and "or another char" parts of the spec mean that we're free to, say, specify that the number of lines *must* be omitted and that the asterisks should be replaced by, say, `X`es for our program to work?

Comment: @Bakuriu I don't understand your comment. If you write a program in ASCII, then each character is a byte. If you write in UTF-32, then each character is 4 bytes. The shortest code in *bytes*, not characters, wins according to the current spec. It sounds like you want the encoding to become a requirement, but I don't see why it is necessary. Did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: The "length in bytes of a program" is **not** a well-defined mathematical function. If someone provides an answer saying "it's N bytes long" someone else can say "no it's M". *And both can be correct*. The "length in bytes of a program encoded with encoding X", with fixed "X" **is** a well-defined mathematical function. The "number of unicode codepoints in the source of a program" **is** a well defined mathematical functions. I believe **the** most basic requirement for a correct scoring *is* to be a well-defined mathematical function of the program.

Comment: @Bakuriu When you say 'The number of bytes in encoding X' do you mean 'The number of bytes when converted into encoding X'?

Comment: @kitcar2000 I mean *represented* in memory. Unicode is an abstract way to define a string. Encodings are the actual mean to store them in memory. If you care for the length in bytes, i.e. when stored in memory, you **must** specify *how* you are storing them (i.e. in which encoding). Otherwise everyone could just say "I used my made up encoding where this is represented with 1 byte" and be done (more real world example: APL's made up encoding where it "happens" that all APL's unicode commands take only one byte). *Every* program can be represented in 1 byte with a suitable encoding.

Comment: @Bakuriu The definition of a byte is 8 bits in memory, so if you are using let's say UTF-16 encoding, `abc` uses 6 bytes because one character is stored in 16 bits.  APL is still storing its data with a certain number of bits per character.  The encoding only affects how the data should be read, not what the data is eg. byte 217 is always 217 just can be understood in different ways.  Also, the example of your made up encoding is a variation of [this issue](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1071/17148) in the standard loopholes on meta.

Comment: @kitcar2000 Let's say `abc` is a valid program that solves the current question. What should be its score? 6? 3? 12? The first would be its score when represented in UTF-16, the second if it was represented as ASCII/utf-8, the third if it was represented in UTF-32. *This* is what I mean. According to the definition in the question the score of the program `abc` can be **all** those values. Who is going to choose which on is right?

Comment: @Bakuriu You should see the Things to Note section of the [code-golf tag wiki](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info).  It specifies the rules for when the encoding is unspecified.

Comment: Based on some answers missing some of the rules, I've added two examples and moved the entire example block below the rules block for additional clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 30 characters

```
n/(\(;n*'*'/{@.!'.'*+([]+@+}*\
```

[Run online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJxd2VydHl1aW9wYXNkZmdoamtsenhjdmJubQo0CioqKioqICogKioqCiogICAqICogKgoqICAgKiAqICoKKioqKiogKiAqKioKIgoKbi8oXCg7bionKicve0AuIScuJyorKFtdK0ArfSpcCg%3D%3D&run=true).

*Examples:*

```
> qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
> 4
> ***** * ***
> *   * * *
> *   * * *
> ***** * ***

qwert y uio
p   a s d
f   g h j
klzxc v bnm

> qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
> 1
> ***** * ***

qwert y uio
pasdfghjklzxcvbnm

> qwerty
> 2
> ***** * ***
> *   * * *

qwert y ...
.   . . .
```

Answer (score 10):

## Perl 6: <s>60 characters</s> *EDIT*: 38 points (see bottom)

```
  #C#O     D#E#G#O       #L#
#F    #.#S#       T#A#C#K
  get\     .subst(       "*"
,{    shift       BEGIN [
  get\     .comb,\       "."
xx    * ]},       :g)\ .\
  say\     xx get\       ()\
#E    #X#C#       H#A#N#G
  #E#.     #C#O#M#       #!#
```

If you don't appreciate my terrible art skills, here's the golf:

```
get.subst("*",{shift BEGIN [get.comb,"."xx*]},:g).say xx get
```

This one does weird things with evaluation times.

First, the `BEGIN` keyword forces `[get.comb, "." xx *]` to be evaluated first, putting into an array the list of characters that make up "the code", followed by an infinite amount of `"."`s.

Next, the `get` at the end is evaluated, getting the number of lines of the ASCII art template. The `xx` operator repeats the first part of the program this many times. This makes more sense when you realize that `code() xx count()` is basically sugar for `code() for 1..count()`: `count()` should be evaluated first.

Finally, the `get` in the beginning of the program gets a line of the ASCII art template and substitutes every `"*"` with a value shifted off of the beginning of the array we made before everything else (`{shift BEGIN …}`).

### EDIT:

Golfed down to 37 characters, plus one for the command line switch:

```
perl6 -pe's:g[\*]=shift BEGIN [get.comb,"."xx*]'
```

This is the same concept as the original, the `-p` switch iterating over each line (after the `BEGIN` has read in "the code"), and substituting all `*`s with the next letter from "the code" before printing it. The input format for this shouldn't include the number of lines of the format.

Answer (score 6):

### Ruby 2.0, <del>53</del> 52 characters

```ruby
c=gets.chop
$><<gets($n).gsub(?*){c.slice!(0)||?.}+c
```

As per the spec, doesn't use the 'number of lines' paramater.

Example run:

```
qwertyuiopasd
***** * ***
*   * * *
*   * * *
***** * ***
```

Output:

```
qwert y uio
p   a s d
.   . . .
..... . ...
```

Comment: `./ascii.rb: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token \`('

./ascii.rb: line 2: \`puts gets($n).gsub(?*){c.slice!(0)||?.},c'`

Comment: @Charles I can't seem to get that error in any version of Ruby I have installed.  Here's the code running on IDEONE: http://ideone.com/3HG3Fb

Comment: weird.  IDEONE worked fine.  Anyway, you can save a char (the space) by replacing `puts ` with `$><<` and changing the `,` at the end to a `+`

Comment: @Charles Good call.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>63</s> <s>86</s> <s>83</s> 82 bytes

*+20 bytes thanks @Veskah*

```powershell
param($s,$p)-join($p|% *ht($s|% Le*)'*'|% t*y|%{if($_-eq42){$_=$s[$i++]}"$_."[0]})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBNb4JAEL3vr3jRtcsimqb1amIvPfXYmzGEyiJYPlZ2USny2@kAbWNnM5uXN/PeTEYXF1WaWKVpxyOs0XQ6KIPM4cbjWi6ORZI7XN9mcGNLJIE35UrhCkLWrW@zJokc7i/UafUkG@6vudnyZD7ftRPuLyfbx10ru5axjcM8R5xomK2rpNCBCaNDfPxMv67780eeCY9tBHP7AD3XZS6AAd@ju7rYDJLBEjXIlGlqDGAQsojQATGObJiAM2gGSWS/xXusVB4KTwxmFASJA5FLITHGFGWVKjz3gtegRJ8vl6AeZfT/I@WfYMWYxA0zNKy3oTuCa0p11WpvVUg35v5YKpWpUkvEA52eG@ob@Al3fkp01T@dnLBxrV/ZFFW@L7JM5RY2TgzSJFewBcLE6DSoMfYZ1nbf)

Less golfed:

```powershell
param($string,$pattern)

$chars = $pattern |
    % PadRight ($string|% Length) '*' |
    % toCharArray |
    % {
        if($_-eq42){$_=$string[$i++]}    # $_ can become $null
        "$_."[0]                         # $_ or '.' if $_ is $null
    }
-join($chars)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 bytes

```
sVè-)iVr-@t°J1 ª'.
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=c1boLSlpVnItQHSwSjEgqicu&input=InF3ZXJ0eXVpb3Bhc2RmZ2hqa2x6eGN2Ym5tIgoiLS0tLS0gLSAtLS0KLSAgIC0gLSAtCi0gICAtIC0gLQotLS0tLSAtIC0tLSI)

Comment: `sVl)iVr-@t°J1 ª'.` works for 17

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance, that would fail on the 4th rule.a

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 142 bytes

> @h is the input text
>
> @ is the pattern

```sql
DECLARE @h varchar(max)='qwertyuiopasdfg'
DECLARE @ varchar(max)='
***** * ***
*   * * *
*   * * *
***** * ***'

WHILE @ like'%*'SELECT @=left(@,charindex('*',@)-1)+left(@h+'.',1)+stuff(@,1,charindex('*',@),''),@h=substring(@h,2,999)PRINT
concat(@,'
'+@h)
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1039856/the-easy-way-to-code-golf-ascii-art)**

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-plF`, 51 bytes

```perl
$_=join'',<>;s/\*/@F?shift@F:'.'/ge;$\=$/.join'',@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYrPzNPXV3Hxs66WD9GS9/Bzb44IzOtxMHNSl1PXT891VolxlZFXw@qzMHt///C8tSiksrSzPyCxOKUtPSMrOycqorksqS8XEMjYxNTLhMuLRBQAEItLS4tBQUFMBuZhZD/l19QkpmfV/xf19dUz8DQ4L9uQY4bAA)

Comment: You're right; I missed that requirement.  It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript - 199

```
text="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
pattern="***** * ***\n*   * * *\n*   * * *\n***** * ***";

function p(a,c){z=c.length,y=a.length,x=0;for(i=z;i-->0;)if(c[i]=="*")x+=1;if(x-y>0)for(i=x-y;i-->0;)a+=".";for(;i++<x;)c=c.replace(new RegExp("[*]"),a[i]);console.log(c);console.log(a.substring(x))}

p(text,pattern);
```

Outputs extra characters in text input if not used in pattern, uses padded "." if there's not enough.

EDIT: modified to be a function accepting text and pattern

Comment: Nice... but this uses hard-coded input.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to handle stdin from JS, especially with the newlines. Suggestions?

Comment: @Matt Node? Spidermonkey?

Comment: Perhaps making it a function...

Comment: Converted to function for now, thanks.

Comment: There is a lot of obvious ways to reduce the number of characters : `x+=1` to `x++`, `x-y>0` to `x>y`, `new RegExp("[x]")` to `/x/`...

Comment: 136 : `function p(a,c){x=c.split(s='*').length-1;for(i=x-a.length;i--;)a+='.';for(;i++<x;)c=c.replace(s,a[i]);console.log(c+'\n'+a.substring(x))}`

Comment: Been out of the game for a few weeks, obviously slipping missing those simple ones. Nice improvements too.

Comment: @TheDoctor Your question explicitly states you should **not** write a function. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) -<s>96</s> 87

```
r=(c,p)=>{c=0+c;console.log(p.replace(/\*/g,t=>(c=c.substr(1),c[0]||'.'))+c.substr(1))}
```

Note: As [suggested by the OP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26652/the-easy-way-to-code-golf-ascii-art#comment58958_26662), I am using a function. But if its required to have a program, here's a **93 chars solution**.

```
c=0+(x=prompt)();p=x();console.log(p.replace(/\*/g,t=>(c=c.substr(1),c[0]||'.'))+c.substr(1))
```

EDIT1: Major change, I don't know why I didn't realize this for the first time :P Saved 40 chars.

---

**Usage**:

```
// r(code, pattern)
r("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm", "***** * ***\n*   * * *\n*   * * *\n***** * ***\n** ** **)
```

---

**Test Input**: (without unneeded optional number as per spec)

```
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
***** * ***
*   * * *
*   * * *
***** * ***
** ** **
```

**Output**:

```
qwert y uio
p   a s d
f   g h j
klzxc v bnm
.. .. ..      // not much text was there to fill *s - replaced with dots as per spec
```

---

**Ungolfed Code**:

```
function run(code, pattern){
  code = "0" + code;  // prepend a zero; useful for the substring operation ahead

  pattern = pattern.replace(/\*/g, function(){  // replace the dots
    // by removing the first letter of code
    // and replacing dot with the first-letter of leftover code 
    // and if it isn't there (code finished)
    // return a dot

    code = code.substr(1); 
    return c[0] || '.';
  });
  }

  // after this operation; code contains the last letter of the org. code

  console.log(  p +  // the pattern has now code
                "\n" +   // and a newline
                c.substr(1) // if there is more than one letter of code left; display it
             );
}
```

---

It would be very nice to hear of any suggestions from users :)

Answer (score 1):

## C, <strike>98</strike>, 91 characters

Here a pretty straight-forward C solution in under 100 characters. This doesn't use the line count input. (Else a second unneeded gets() would be needed).

```
char b[999],*s;c;main(){gets(s=b);while(~(c=getchar()))putchar(c^42?c:*s?*s++:46);puts(s);}
```

ungolfed:

```
char b[999],*s;c;
main(){
    gets(s=b);
    while(~(c=getchar()))
        putchar(c^42?c:*s?*s++:46);
    puts(s);
}
```

Comment: You can use `puts(s)` instead of `printf("%s",s)` to save 7 bytes.

Comment: @nyuszika7h Thanks! But I don't know if the additional `\n` is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2.7, <del>165</del> <del>155</del> <del>150</del> <del>138</del> 119 characters

Okay, pretty much but I guess it's the tiniest way to do it with Python.

```py
import sys
r=raw_input
l=list(r())
w=sys.stdout.write
for c in"\n".join([r()for _ in[1]*input()]):w(c=='*'and(l and l.pop(0)or'.')or c)
w("".join(l))
```

**Edit:** new functional 1.0.1 version with even less bytes used:

**Edit2:** `map(r,['']*input())` instead of `[r()for _ in[1]*input()]` and removed unused import

**Edit3:** `'>'*input()` instead of `['']*input()` saving one character and adding prompt character for pattern :)

```py
r=raw_input
l=list(r())
print''.join(map(lambda c:c=='*'and(l and l.pop(0)or'.')or c,"\n".join(map(r,'>'*input())))+l)
```

Comment: You can use `(['.']+l).pop(0)` instead of `(len(l)and l.pop(0)or'.')` to save 9 bytes. And `input()` instead of `int(r())` to save 1 byte.

Comment: Thanks for `input`! Unfortunately your first advice doesn't work because it outputs dots as long as string length>0.

Comment: I see why my suggestion isn't correct. Try `(l+['.']).pop(0)` instead, but if that doesn't work either, you can still save 4 bytes by using `l and` instead of `len(l)and`.

Comment: `(l+['.']).pop(0)` doesn't remove elements from `l` so only first character is printed but `l` condition works :)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 70 characters

```
@_=split'',<>=~s/\n//r;<>;print/\*/?shift@_||'.':$_ for map{split''}<>
```

Or, without boundary check, 56 characters

```
@_=split'',<>;<>;print/\*/?shift@_:$_ for map{split''}<>
```

Note, this code is not using second line as in spec, and can be shortened by three characters `<>;`

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, <del>166 156 111</del> 106

Reads from standard input, doesn't take a line count. First line of input is the code you want to put into ascii art, all subsequent lines are the ascii art, consisting of the `@` character. **Input has a maximum length of 999 chars, and is not permitted to contain forward slashes**. (I chose not to use `*` or `#` because they have special meanings in Bash).

```bsh
read -n999 -d/ i p
while [[ $p =~ @ && -n $i ]];do
p="${p/@/${i:0:1}}"
i=${i:1}
done
tr @ .<<<"$p"
echo $i
```

**WARNING:** This program uses a file called `p`. After executing the program, delete `p` - it will confuse the program the second time you run it.

Most of the work here is done by

```bsh
p="${p/@/${i:0:1}}"
i=${i:1}
```

The first line substitutes the first `@` in the art with the first character of the code. The second line removes the first character of the code.

If there is not enough code to fill the shape, a newline is printed after the main ascii art output by `echo $i`.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 122 bytes

```cs
var n=ReadLine();int k=0;foreach(var z in In.ReadToEnd())Write(z>33?(n+new string('.',999))[k++]:z);Write(n.Substring(k));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcqxDoIwGATgnaf4N9qixIQJG3RyMHFSEwfjUKFAxfxoW0T78lXURO@WS@7LzTg3yvub0IDZWopipVASyhVaaLIJL1stRV6TAThQCEuMB7ZtF1gQSndaWUncLEnmBCOUPRirFVYkjMNRmqaU7psoOkwd5R@K8aY7fk1DKff@2kttH51qL8IUZVWfmrO75wEbAq8yFjAAeO//9fuf)

Comment: Due to lack of specifics and other answers doing it, you can probably ditch the `"\n"+` to append the extra characters to the same line

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
s0¢.$«0¹S.;0'.:
```

Takes the code as first input, pattern as second (with `0` instead of `#`).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/2ODQIj2VQ6sNDu0M1rM2UNez@v@/sDy1qKSyNDO/ILE4JS09Iys7p6oiuSwpL9fQyNjElEtJSckABBSA0MCAy0BBQQHMRmYh5IGqAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R9aVqnkmVdQWmKlcHg/l39pCZippBPhUvm/2ODQIj2VQ6sNKoP1rA3U9az@6xzaZv9fSUnJAAQUgNDAgMtAQUEBzEZmIeSBqrmilQrLU4tKKksz8wsSi1PS0jOysnOqKpLLkvJylXTwSBoaGZuYYqpQigUA).

**<s>18</s> 15 bytes alternative by taking the inputs in reversed order:**

```
0¢.$¹ì0IS.;0'.:
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4NAiPZVDOw@vMfAM1rM2UNez@v9fSUnJAAQUgNDAgMtAQUEBzEZmIeSBqrkKy1OLSipLM/MLEotT0tIzsrJzqiqSy5Lycg2NjE1MAQ).

**Explanation:**

```python
s                # Swap with implicit inputs, so the stack order is now: [code, pattern]
 0¢              # Count the amount of "0" in the pattern
   .$            # Remove that many leading characters from the code
     «           # Append it to the (implicit) pattern input
      0¹S.;      # Replace every "0" one by one with the characters of the first code input
           0'.: '# Then replace any remaining "0" with "."
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly as result)
```